# jQuery and multiple classes selecting only a single class

Tags: jquery

I have a buttons like these:

```
<button class="sOne sTwo sThree addUser">Click Me</button>
<button class="sOne sTwo sThree delUser">Click Me</button>
<button class="sOne sTwo sThree blockUser">Click Me</button>
```

I need to detect only the class `addUser` because in my jQuery I do:

```
$('.addUser,.delUser,.blockUser').click(function() {
var act = $(this).attr('class');
switch (act)
case 'addUser':
case 'delUser':
case 'blockUser':
});
```

Problem is, I get the entire class in there which is: `sOne sTwo sThree addUser`, and all my script fails.

How can I detect only the class `addUser` or `delUser` etc.

Comment: Use [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of `switch` use `if` and `else if` like below,

```
$('.addUser,.delUser,.blockUser').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass('addUser') {
       //code for addUser
  } else if ($this.hasClass('delUser') {
       //code for delUser
  } else if ($this.hasClass('blockUser') {
       //code for blockUser
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `hasClass()`:

```
$('.addUser,.delUser,.blockUser').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('addUser')) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

It might be worth evaluating whether you could give each element it's own click handler though, if all the code for each is different.

Comment: `It might be worth evaluating whether you could give each element it's own click handler though, if all the code for each is different.` You mean... ?

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the ability to change the way the code is generated, but you'd have a much easier time leaving class to govern the styling or common functions, and using a unique ID property for each to which you can bind unique functions.